# Analisar os 3 ultimos registros de uma tabela usando PHP

Tags: php

Galera preciso de uma ajuda.

Eu tenho uma tabela onde no campo preco preciso avaliar se o preco dos 3 ultimos registros foram maior do que 50. 
Se sim eu tenho que exibir um alerta.

Bem pegar os 3 últimos registros eu conseguiria usando um select com desc e limit 3. Se fosse somete para exibir seria fácil o problema é como avaliar os 3 últimos registros e saber se os 3 foram maior que 50 ou nao.

A parte do alerta também é facil, eu conseguindo avaliar o dado dou em echo.

Comment: Você sinalizou que é php, mas qual é o servidor de banco? Qual o driver de banco que tá usando? Qual é a estrutura dessa tabela de preços? Detalhe mais os atributos do caso pra ter uma resposta melhor.

Comment: Banco: MySql. Drive eu entendo que você queira saber se estou usando Mysqli ou PDO, se for isso a resposta é PDO. A estrutura da tabela seria id, nome do produto e preço. O que eu preciso é só emitir um alerta quando os 3 últimos produtos adicionados na tabela custarem mais de 50 seguidamente. Por exemplo: caneta 40, lapis 60, mouse 70. Neste caso o alerta não é emitido pois somente os 2 últimos produtos foram maior que 50, logo nada acontece. Porém se caneta 60 lapis 70 mouse 80 ai exibiria um alerta Parabéns os 3 ultimos produtos custaram mais de 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um campo calculado no select que sinalize se o valor está ou não abaixo de 50:

```
select preco,
       if preco < 50 then 'S' else 'N' endif as preco_menor
from tabela
order by data desc limit 3
```

assim você terá os tres ultimos precos e cada um deles sinalizado se o valor está abaixo ou nao de 50 ou outro valor que voce desejar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.  Pelo que eu entendi eu teria que criar um view com um campo virtual que seria a referencia, no caso você usou o S. Sendo assim seria exibido na tela os 3 ultimos registros com a letra s. Agora vem a questão como faria um if onde eu diria if os 3 ultimos registros = s echo uma mensagem?

Comment: Exato. Tem várias maneiras, aqui tem um exemplo possível: 
$sql = "select preco,  if preco < 50 then 'S' else 'N' endif as preco_menor from tabela order by data desc limit 3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // exibir cada linha 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["preco_menor"] = "S") {
            echo "Preco abaixo de 50,00". "<br";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Nada a exibir";
}

Comment: Obrigado você resolveu o problema.